# What is the result of this recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

What does this recursive function return?

```
def fun(a,b):

      if(b==0):

            return a

      else:

            return fun(b, a%b)
```

I tried checking on some numbers for example it returns 3 for 15,6

Comment: It should return 3 not 2 to start with.

Comment: It implements a certain well-known algorithm, but if you aren't familiar with the algorithm or what it computes, then observing the output for a bunch of different arguments probably won't help much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can anyone explain how this code works? GCD, Recursive, Euclidian algorighm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156099/can-anyone-explain-how-this-code-works-gcd-recursive-euclidian-algorighm)

Answer (score 3):

This calculates the greatest common divisor between a and b.

See this question for the proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59147/why-gcda-b-gcdb-a-bmod-b-understanding-euclidean-algorithm

The greatest common divisor (gcd) of two numbers `a` and `b` is the largest number that divides both a and b.

Note: `f(6, 15)` should return 3, as 3 is the largest number that divides both 6 and 15